# First time using Parallel.ForEach UI still locking up

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

What I am trying to do here is loop a listview full of URLs, check if the source code contains a string, if it does then update the UI listview with `YES` or `NO`.

I had forgotten about the `Parallel.ForEach` method, so decided to try it out (I'm not even sure if it's the best solution for this)

```
Parallel.ForEach(listViewMain.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>(), row =>
{
    try
    {

        string html = Helpers.GetRequest(row.Text);

        if (html.Contains(txtBoxFind.Text))
        {
            row.SubItems[3].Text = "YES";
        }
        else
        {
            row.SubItems[3].Text = "NO";
        }

    } catch(Exception) {

    }
});
```

The process is fairly simple doing it without the `Parallel.ForEach` but the UI is still locking up, have i implemented it right? `Helpers.GetRequest` simply returns the raw HTML to be checked, i thought using the `Parallel.ForEach` would stop the UI locking while processing or have i got it wrong, any help is appreciated.

Comment: What  technology is this ? It would be nice if you've added relevant tags

Comment: Can you share the code of `Helpers.GetRequest()` method?

Comment: It will block because code is not async. It's calculating on the main thread.

Comment: One of the threads is probably still the UI thread.  You want this happening only in other threads, i.e. a worker thread should be doing this.

Comment: You're accessing the UI thread that's why and you're doing it for every item.

Comment: If the `Helpers.GetRequest(row.Text);` does what it's name says. This should **NOT** be done using the `Parallel.ForEach()`. `Parallel.ForEach()` is only useful for CPU bound work. Not for IO bound work. Use the TaskLibrary for this.

Comment: What do you trying to achieve, parallelism (for performance) or asynchrony (for responsive UI)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before we begin, do note that `Parallel.ForEach` in itself is a blocking call, so that is why you experience the UI being not responsive.

A good read is **[Avoid Executing Parallel Loops on the UI Thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/potential-pitfalls-in-data-and-task-parallelism#avoid-executing-parallel-loops-on-the-ui-thread)** from the MS docs:

> ... the parallel loop blocks the UI thread on which it’s executing until all iterations are complete.

That said, you should use a `Task` based approach if not dealing with CPU bound work but with I/O bound work. Since you are dealing with network calls you should stick to tasks. Try this:

```cs
    public async Task DoSomething()
    {
        // Process the items parallel
        await Task.WhenAll(listViewMain.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Select(async row =>
        {
            // wrap the long running call in a async Task
            string html = await Task.Run(() => Helpers.GetRequest(row.Text));

            // no need for context capturing and invokes, this is running on the UI thread
            var containsText = html.Contains(txtBoxFind.Text);
            if (containsText)
            {
                row.SubItems[3].Text = "YES";
            }
            else
            {
                row.SubItems[3].Text = "NO";
            }
        }));
    }
```

It would be even better when you can make `Helpers.GetRequest(row.Text)` a Task based method, then you could do:

```cs
    public async Task DoSomething()
    {
        // Process the items parallel
        await Task.WhenAll(listViewMain.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Select(async row =>
        {
            // wrap the long running call in a async Task
            string html = await Helpers.GetRequestAsync(row.Text);

            // no need for context capturing and invokes, this is running on the UI thread
            var containsText = html.Contains(txtBoxFind.Text);
            if (containsText)
            {
                row.SubItems[3].Text = "YES";
            }
            else
            {
                row.SubItems[3].Text = "NO";
            }
        }));
    }
```

but we need to see the code of `Helpers.GetRequest(row.Text)` to assist you with that.

**EDIT**

You've shown the code of GetRequest. `WebClient` is not task based, try `HttpClient`:

```cs
public async Task<string> GetRequestAsync(string url)
{
    var html = "";
    using (HttpClient wc = new HttpClient())
    {
        html = await wc.GetStringAsync(url);
    }
    return html;
}
```

Comment: Best solution!!

Comment: Thank you very much guys! the code for the GetRequestAsync is: https://pastebin.com/fn1dMRy8 this is the other isue, the error is "string does not contain a definition for GetAwaiter" i am reading up on the cause of this now :) i also moved ```GetRequestAsync``` out the helpers class to make it more readable.

Comment: I like it, nice one. `Select(async row =>` is a great feature.

Comment: @Graham I have updated my answer to address your code of `GetRequestAsync `

Comment: Thank you very much Peter and everyone! it was a good learning experience too :)

Comment: I suppose the one who downvoted my answer did not have time to explain what is missing or how to improve it?

Answer (score 1):

the `Parallel.ForEach` is executing on the UI thread (current thread) and it will not provide more performance for you in case of non-blocking UI. If you want to avoid the UI block, you could try using the `async` methods, for sample:

```
Task.Run(() => CheckItems());
```

Given you can implement an async version of the `GetRequest` method, you could implement an async method to do this, for sample:

```
public async Task CheckItems()
{
    foreach (var row in listViewMain.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>())
    {
        try
        {    
            string html = await Helpers.GetRequestAsync(row.Text);

            if (html.Contains(txtBoxFind.Text))
            {
                row.SubItems[3].Text = "YES";
            }
            else
            {
                row.SubItems[3].Text = "NO";
            }

        } catch(Exception ex) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to wrap a Task based method in another Task using `Task.Run(() => CheckItems());`? The code is now effectively *not* running on the UI thread

Comment: The code using `await Helpers.GetRequestAsync(row.Text);` in your example does not run parallel, not sure if that is a requirement

Comment: Yes @PeterBons, you're right, I am just assuming that the OP can have (or implement it) an async method to do this, to get the benefits of async methods. I am not sure if this method exists.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the `Parallel.ForEach()` for this. `Parallel.ForEach()` is used for CPU bound work. Not IO.

I would do something like: (I didn't tested it, might contains some typo's) *(used notepad)*

So you might use this for the idea:

```
public async void Button_Click(object sender, EventArg e)
{
    await CheckItems(listViewMain.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>());
}

public async Task CheckItems(IEnumerable<ListViewItem> items)
{
    // Capture the UI thread synchronization.
    var context = SynchronizationContext.Current;

    var tasks = new List<Task>();

    // create tasks.
    foreach (var row in items)
    {
        tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
        {
            // the lookup on a (probably) threadpool thread
            string html = Helpers.GetRequest(row.Text);

            // the processing here..
            var containsText = html.Contains(txtBoxFind.Text);

            // post the result (and touching gui items in the UI thread)
            // this.Invoke() is also and might be the best solution.
            context.Post(() =>
            {
                if (containsText)
                {
                    row.SubItems[3].Text = "YES";
                }
                else
                {
                    row.SubItems[3].Text = "NO";
                }
            });

        }));
    }

    // wait for them
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

---

While I was adding some comment, you could also use the `this.Invoke()` for this (instead of the `SynchronizationContext`)

gtg.

Comment: You could improve it by using an async delegate, so that the thread-pool threads are not blocked (assuming that a `Helpers.GetRequestAsync` is available).

Comment: I don't know if the `Helpers.GetRequestAsync(row.Text);` exists. But I would create one for sure.. Good point.

Comment: Why this context capturing and post stuff? That should not be necessary when dealing with async / await.